# Randomly Adding sprites on moving background

Tags: android, andengine

I am using the andengine and trying to make a simple racing game.
Here I am able to move the road and able to put the car on the road and it is showing like car is moving.Which is OK for now. Now here are the parts which I am finding worrisome and not able to implement.
a. How would I add new sprites(cars) on the moving road at random time in the opposite direction of the target car  and show some trees on the side of the roads(as for now it is only a simple road).
b. How would I increase and decrease the speed of both background road and the car on the road.
I tried to do but application hangs I am also trying to use Sensor-manger class to get the moment of the device.
I know I am asking for a lot but I need some path to start with.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> **How would I add new sprites(cars) on the moving road...**

There are other constructors, but how about

```
Sprite car = new Sprite(X, Y, TextureRegion, context);
```

---

> **... at random time ...**

In a registered entity update thread:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
int chanceOfNewCar = 5;  
if (randomInt < chanceOfNewCar) {
   // Add your car code.
}
```

---

> **... the opposite direction of the target car...**

No idea how your target car is moving, but here's a wild stab:

```
newCarVelocity = -targetCarVelocity;
```

---

> **... and show some trees on the side of the roads...**

See the above example for displaying a car sprite.

---

> **.. How would I increase and decrease the speed of both background road...**

The road has speed?  Do you mean a moving background?  If so, move the car faster and have a camera chasing it (so the background appears to pan faster).

---

> **.. and the car on the road...**

The car and the road have speed?  How are you moving them now?

---

> **... I tried to do but application hangs...**

Debug.

---

> **... I am also trying to use Sensor-manger class to get the moment of the device ...**

Cool.

Comment: hi,@CamFred great..keep in Touch mates.

Comment: Watch, now someone is going to clean up the language of the question and my approach to answering is going to look manic.

Comment: Thnx for the reply I will give it a shot and will come up to you with the output..thnxx again

Comment: Sounds good, @vyas.  Let me know about that green checkmark if things work out. ;)

Comment: So... @vyas .. was it helpful enough to be marked as a correct answer? (i.e., green checkmark to he left of the votecount).  I know, I know, I'm fishing for reputation points here, but approving an answer when you feel it's appropriate helps the community by encouraging future answers, etc.